# How can I test $rootScope.$emit event?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I have below code in `abc` controller:

```
   $rootScope.$on('selectedItem', function (event, data) {
       vm.selectedItem = data;
   });
```

And the caller function is in `xyz` controller:

```
  function doThis(){
     $rootScope.$emit('selectedItem', 'somedata');
  }
```

How can I reproduce or mock this scenario in karma test?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For first controller (`abc`), where you listen to it using `$rootScope.$on`, you can first `$rootScope.$emit` it and `$scope.$digest()` it. So that you can receive it in `$on`.

```
var rootScope;
beforeEach(inject(function(_$rootScope_) {
    rootScope = _$rootScope_;
}));

describe("some function", function() {
    it("should receive selectedItem with $on", function() {
        rootScope.$emit('selectedItem', 'somedata');
        $scope.$digest();
        expect(vm.selectedItem).toEqual('somedata');
    });
});
```

And for second controller (`xyz`), You can `spy` on `$rootScope.$emit`. And `expect` it to be called in `xyz` controller. Like this:

```
var rootScope;
beforeEach(inject(function(_$rootScope_) {
    rootScope = _$rootScope_;
    spyOn(rootScope, '$emit');
}));

describe("doThis function", function() {
    it("should $emit selectedItem", function() {
        vm.doThis(); // or if you use $scope, call it that way
        expect(rootScope.$emit).toHaveBeenCalledWith('selectedItem');
    });
});
```

Comment: No need to spy the `$emit` function. You already test the side effect: `expect(vm.selectedItem).toEqual('somedata');` and that's completely enough.

Comment: You could even remove the need for `$injector`, and replace with `_$rootScope_`. The code would be cleaner.  
`beforeEach((inject(function(_$rootScope_)) ..`

Comment: @Mik378 yep did that too, `_$rootScope_` is cleaner

Comment: Yes, but now you can remove the `$injector` parameter and you will end up with a great code :). Additionally, it's a good practice to avoid to be tied to technical concepts in test labels. **'should receive selectedItem'** is enough.

Comment: I highly appreciate your answer, but its not working for me. I am spying on the `xyz controller spec` the selectedItem call is happening successfully. But in `abc controller spec`. I have written code like this: `it("should receive selectedItem with $on", function() {
            $rootScope.$emit('selectedItem', 'somedata');
            $scope.$digest();
            expect(vm.selectedItem).toEqual('somedata');
        });` . But its not entering the on method, and the somedata value is not being set. Its still expecting `none` which was set by default.

Comment: @Mithun I don't see a reason why it wouldn't work. Make sure you have injected `$rootScope` and `$scope` properly and you are emitting the exact event

Comment: Got it, there was a unwanted spy. That was the culprit, removed this: `spyOn($rootScope, '$emit');` from abc controller. Everything worked fine, thanks a ton

Answer (score 2):

Using Jasmine, it could look like this:

```
var rootScope;
beforeEach(inject(function($injector) {
    rootScope = $injector.get('$rootScope');
    spyOn(rootScope, '$emit');
}));

describe("$rootScope event testing", function() {
    it("should $emit selectedItem", function() {
        expect(rootScope.$emit).toHaveBeenCalledWith('selectedItem');
    });
});
```

Comment: `Expected spy $emit to have been called with [ 'selectedItem' ] but it was never called`. Also on my beforeEach function block, there is one more spy declaration like: `spyOn($rootScope, '$emit').and.callThrough();`. Should i add this spyOn along with that?

Comment: It threw error: already a spy called on emit, so hence removed and tested. But still i get error as: `Expected spy $emit to have been called with [ 'selectedItem' ] but it was never called`