# How to test dynamic name of $rootScope.$emit event?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have read this post, but this post is about the name in $rootscope.emit's is static

[How can I test $rootScope.$emit event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43135747/how-can-i-test-rootscope-emit-event)

My problem is that my emit name is dymaic, how do I test it?

```
vm.$rootScope.$emit('FooEvent' + vm.numberCount, 'Foo');

vm.$rootScope.$on('FooEvent' + (vm.numberCount), function (event, data) {

                });
```

Answer (score 0):

A better way to go about this is to not make the event name dynamic and put `vm.numbercount` into the payload of the event. You can do something like:

```
vm.$rootScope.$emit('FooEvent', 'Foo', vm.numberCount);

vm.$rootScope.$on('FooEvent', function (event, ...args) {
  //   args[0] => 'Foo'
  //   args[1] => vm.numberCount
});
```

Comment: Looks like I have to make the name dynamic, because I used this directive multiple times, so I want to make sure that different directive listen to different event

Comment: Can you post more context about this directive, because this is definitely now what events were made for.

My example still lets you do what you want. In the body of the listener, you can decide what to do based on `vm.numberCount`. Also this lets you attach only one event listener, instead of however many times this directive is being used.